# Firebird/DB2 - referencing column that is declared later

Tags: sql, db2, firebird, create-table

Let's assume we have trivial code like:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  CONSTRAINT greater_than_10 CHECK (id > 10)
);
```

A table with single column and constraint was defined. Now if we switch the order:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
  CONSTRAINT greater_than_10 CHECK (id > 10),
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

> unsuccessful metadata update CREATE TABLE TAB failed Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206 **Column unknown ID**

or:

> [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0205N  **Column, attribute, or period "ID" is not defined in "FIDDLE_QSNXRANMEEPHZPWEWQDV.TAB".**  SQLSTATE=42703 SQLCODE=-205

**[db<>fiddle demo - Firebird](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=df21b0c5e0699c6cd1c204012826c6a0)**

**[db<>fiddle demo - DB2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=3e18ba6bb33d40868a6a01afc205f0d4)**

This behaviour does not exists in any other major RDBMS:

[db<>fiddle demo - Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81b37461381f2865d6d294309b793d6b) - 
[db<>fiddle demo - SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=81b37461381f2865d6d294309b793d6b) - 
[db<>fiddle demo - PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=81b37461381f2865d6d294309b793d6b)

**EDIT:**

It is also applicable for foreign keys that reference the same table:

```
-- here I could define columns in any order, neat feature
CREATE TABLE comments(
  comment_id INT REFERENCES comments(id),
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

[db<>fiddle demo - FK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ecee91785eb7a1e5e0f51ce6889cf6b)

The idea of refering objects that does not exist is present for instance: T-SQL stored procedures deferred name resolution or C/C++ forward declarations.

**EDIT 2:**

This behaviour is even applicalbe for calculated columns:

```
-- SQL Server
CREATE TABLE t(
   col AS (id + 1),
   id INT
);

-- PostgreSQL 12
CREATE TABLE t(
   col INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (id + 1) STORED,
  id INT
);

-- Oracle/MySQL 8.0/MariaDB 10.4
CREATE TABLE t(
  col INT AS (id + 1),
  id INT
);
```

---

**Searching for official documentation/ISO that states if specific order of defining entries at the same level is mandatory.**

Comment: So, the question is ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan The question is if this behavior is canonical in accordance to  standard.

Comment: @LukashSzozda . . . I'm surprised that defining a constraint on a not-yet-defined column works in any database.  I wouldn't even consider writing SQL that way.  I would imagine that the standard doesn't have much to say about this particular topic; it can be rather ambiguous.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, that is a bit strange. That is why I asked a question. It is not restricted to constraints but **[self-referecing foreign keys](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ecee91785eb7a1e5e0f51ce6889cf6b)** too.

Comment: As far as I can tell, at a quick glance, the SQL standard (ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016) doesn't say anything about it. The wording in 11.3 <table definition> is not specific enough to say conclusively if it is allowed or not, or even required.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Understood. So the behaviour is not defined. Please feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE comments(  comment_id INT REFERENCES comments(id),` - creating self-referential tables is dangerous on Firebird and may lead to server crash. Stay warned.

Comment: @Arioch'The So it is a serious bug. Non valid query should return error not a crash of entire system :/

Comment: @LukaszSzozda creating this table does not crash it, but some DML statements later might, like deleting all rows. I do not remember exactly, it was few years ago that I registered that bug in FB tracker.

Comment: P.S. http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-3925 reported in 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, at a quick glance, the SQL standard (ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016) doesn't say anything about it. The wording in 11.3 <table definition> is not specific enough to say conclusively if it is allowed or not, or even required.

Answer (score 3):

One could argue that the behaviour exhibited by Db2 and Firebase is more in line with the declarative nature of SQL. Strongly typed languages, of which SQL is one, typically don't tolerate use of undeclared identifiers.

The SQL standard does not prescribe any order to specifying `<column definition>`s and `<constraint definition>`; it<sup>1</sup> *does* say this, however, with respect to the order of evaluation of syntactic rules (emphasis of the original):

> Where the precedence is not determined by the Formats or by parentheses, effective evaluation of expressions
>   is *generally* performed from left to right. However, it is implementation-dependent whether expressions are
>   *actually* evaluated left to right, particularly when operands or operators might cause conditions to be raised or
>   if the results of the expressions can be determined without completely evaluating all parts of the expression.

In other words, the standard leaves it to the implementation to decide whether it processes table definition clauses in the order in which they are specified, or handle `<column definition>`s first and `<constraint definition>`s later.

Source: Draft specifications of [ISO/IEC 9075-1](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N1951-2000/32N1963T-text_for_ballot-FCD_9075-1.pdf) and [ISO/IEC 9075-2](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N2301-2350/32N2311T-text_for_ballot-CD_9075-2.pdf).

---

1 - ISO/IEC 9075-1, Paragraph 6.3.3.3 *Rule evaluation order*.

Comment: Good point, although expressions are something different than a table definition. I'm not sure if the rule you quote apply here.

Comment: Thanks for posting it. It looks were are closer to find a definitive answer.  I am also a bit not convinced if quote related "expressions" is the same as for constraint/column. Nevertheless it is a clue, and I we could guess it is working the same "by analogy".

Comment: These are _syntax_ rules, which apply to the syntax evaluation of any SQL statements.

Comment: @mustaccio However, the quote is concerned with evaluation order and precedence of expressions, and a CREATE TABLE is not an expression, nor are the definitions inside the CREATE TABLE. That said, rereading 11.3 <table definition>, it does say - paraphrasing - that a create table results in a set of column definitions and a set of table constraint definitions, and in that view, you could argue that the order between column definitions and table constraint definitions is not relevant as they are separate sets.

Comment: Based on your expression above, your interpretation of the word "expression" seems to only include value expressions, while the paragraph I quote speaks about the order of evaluation of syntactic, access, and general rules that apply to all statements defined by the standard.